# Outlook not so good

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

As a whole, things aren't looking very bright,
Remove my rear, and something's just not right,
Remove my front, and you'll be at death's door, so crummy,
Remove my middle, and you might find me quite scummy,

What am I?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As a whole, things aren't looking very bright,

> **portend**  - to serve as a warning or omen.

Remove my rear, and something's just not right,

> port - the left side of a vessel.

Remove my front, and you'll be at death's door, so crummy,

> end - our final time.

Remove my middle, and you might find me quite scummy,

> pond - could be surfaced with scum.